# Checking if a nested child node has a value if the key of the parent node is unknown(eg. Firebase generated UID)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image: My Firebase Structure]

I am trying to query a firebase structured data in which I want to find out if particular nested node contains a value. The image attached is my structure. Please refer the figure.

Now my question is

I want to check if the `tag` attribute which is the child `confession` node has the value `BE_CS_B_boy`, but I don't know the parent key of the `confession` node (ie the Firebase generated UID)*. So how can I query it?

How should I traverse to get to the `tag` node to query it in Firebase. Because to go to the `tag` node I need to go through `confession` node and to go through `confession` node I need to mention the parent key (in this case it is the Firebase generated UID)

Note: My root node name is `users` as shown in the image attached. Please refer the figure.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to query across two levels, which is not possible in the Firebase Realtime Database's query model. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Firebase Realtime Database.

The alternative (and Firebase Realtime Database way of thinking) is to create another root level node with the info you need to retrieve, for example:

```
vconfess
  - confessions_in_tags
    - tag_id
      - confession_id_1
      - confession_id_2
```

And, by doing so, you have to keep your denormalised data synchronised.